# overriding hostname in vagrant chef solo recipe

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

Writing my first vagrant chef solo recipe I figured something simple, like changing the hostname.  In the vagrant file, I have this;

```
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "../../chef/cookbooks"
    chef.roles_path = "../../chef/roles"
    chef.data_bags_path = "../../chef/data_bags"

    chef.json = { :hostname => "foofoo" }
    chef.add_recipe "myrecipe"
```

in myrecipe/recipes/default.rb;

```
myvar = node[:hostname]

template "/tmp/myfile" do
    source "myfile.erb"
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode 0644
    variables(
        :myvar => myvar
    )
end
```

in myrecipe/templates/default/myfile.erb;

```
<%= @myvar %>
```

This wouldn't actually work. /tmp/myfile kept ending up with the real hostname from /etc/hostname. After banging my head a long while, I hit on these changes;

in the vagrant file;

```
chef.json = { :myhostname => "foofoo" }
```

in the recipe file;

```
myvar = node[:myhostname]
```

So, it seems ':hostname' is special somehow, but try as I might, I can't find any documentation that explains why, or how to override it, or what other 'special' values there might be available.

Most of the documentation seems to assume some level of competence I haven't reached yet. So, I might have seen the answer and not recognized it.  Can anyone point me to the 'absolute beginner' docs that would explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: this were exactly my first experiments with chef-solo too and: changing the hostname ist **not** the simplest thing one can do (because for the rest of the Chef run the old hostname remains so you have to do ugly things to restart Chef etc...) ;-)

Second: `node['hostname']` is special indeed (it's a so-called [automatic attribute](http://docs.opscode.com/ohai_automatic_attributes.html)), it gets updated from the target host via [ohai](http://docs.opscode.com/ohai.html) so you can use it in your templates e.g..

Edit: You may use [this cookbook](https://github.com/franco/chef-hostname) for applying the hostname.

Comment: is there a way to change it in the vagrant file then?  For example, I am able to set the VM MAC (`node[:macaddress]`) using `config.vm.base_mac = "auto"`.

Comment: I found `config.vm.host_name` in the vagrant 1.0.x docs, but can't find anything remotely similar in the new version docs.  I do know from experimentation that it doesn't work - `vm: the following settings don't exist: host_name`

Comment: It is possible with Chef only but it's not pretty. For me I crafted the rule that I will apply any network related settings (and hostname is one) by hand even in Chef environments for two reasons: a) the bootstrapping problem and b) the risk of failures and losing connectivity

Comment: I found in the new vagrant docs, it is now `config.vm.hostname`.