# How can I override the Chef node name in vagrant?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm developing a Chef cookbook that I'm testing with Vagrant and chef-solo.  The recipes look at `node.name` to make certain decisions.  In order to test various variants of that I would like to override that attribute for test runs from Vagrant.  So I tried

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    ...
    chef.json = {
      'name' => 'randomhostname',
    }
  end
end
```

but seems to have no effect.

I understand that the `name` attribute defaults to the `hostname` attribute, which is managed by ohai (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198448/overriding-hostname-in-vagrant-chef-solo-recipe)), but is there a way to override the `name` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    ...
    chef.node_name = 'node_name'
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  It's apparently not documented.

Comment: True. I found this out because a user of [`Vagrant::Butcher`](http://github.com/cassianoleal/vagrant-butcher) filed a bug. :)

Comment: The documentation is being fixed: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1780

Answer (score 3):

If name defaults to the hostname of the vm then could you just change the hostname?

```
config.vm.hostname = "new.host.name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no way - it's a so called automatic attribute and therefore has *always* the highest priority and overwrites everything you specify. Is it possible for you to use a different attribute or which cookbook are you going to convince that the node's name is something different than Chef thinks?